# update column with different values sqlite database android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a hidden database with 7 columns, one of which is a price and whose values ​​are null. I want to enter some value in the field column for id = 1, then for id = 2 I enter another value etc. and when I fill in the price column I want to update the whole. Is that possible? 
My code updates only one value

```
public boolean updateData(String id,String name, String number_phone, String about, Integer price, String color){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
    contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, number_phone);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, about);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, price);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, color);

    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, " ID = ?" , new String[]{id});
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your question but from what i understand this could might help you out.

If you want only one field values to be updated then you need to use for loop.
In onCreate method call this with the array of prices that you want to be updated in table's each row. 
Array of prices should not be greater than no. of rows exist in table.

```
for(int i=0;i<(no. of rows in table);i++){
updateData(rowId,priceArray[i]);
}
```

Now the update method will be like.

```
public boolean updateData(String id, Integer price){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_5, price);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, " ID = ?" , new String[]{id});
    return true;
}
```

If you want to update certain rows for example {1,4,5} then you have to update it one by one by calling updateData method with id and prices .

But if you want same value of price field to be updated in certain rows like above {1,4,5} than you can

```
public boolean updateData(Integer price){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_5, price);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, " ID = ?" , new String[]{1,4,5});
        return true;
    }
```